# Testng on IntelliJ no output after tests are ignored

Tags: java, mockito, testng, tdd

Is there a way to get the cause of the tests being ignored when Testng ignores the tests?

In the console, after a long list of names of the files built with no result stated,
then all I can see is:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/user1/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.1/temp-testng-customsuite.xml

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

From what I learned, it can be any runtime error. Like IllegalArgumentException etc.

As long as it's during building process, no error message will be displayed.

Is there a more effective way to debug with the missing log?

Answer (score 1):

Then add a `Assert.Ignore("message_here");` to your test code... but ignoring tests is a bad practice. And test SHOULD fail and stop the execution on unexpected exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

> The default `configfailurepolicy` for testng is skip, i.e if any test
>   fails in suite it will skip the remaining.

If you want your tests to run even after failing previous tests the add below attribute in `<suite>` tag of temp-testng-customsuite.xml

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="10" verbose="10" configfailurepolicy="continue">
```